How to add opacity to the Background property in Style.Trigger?
I want to change background color of an element on mouse hover.
I have the following code:
<Border.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Border">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" >
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Border.Style>

There is no opacity property in Trigger section of the Border.Style when setting Background color. I don't want 100% white background.
How can I add opacity?

The simpliest (I totally forgot!) is to add alpha channel to RGB color (ARGB format), like below:
Background="#DD0000FF"

Other ways
There's Opacity property that you can use.
In order to set Opacity on the color, you can define SolidColorBrush with Opacity property set to appropriate value and then use it in background.
Here's how you can trigger change to multiple properties in XAML and also define color with opacity
<Border>
    <Border.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush
            x:Key="WindowBrush"
            Opacity="0.5"
            Color="Brown" />
    </Border.Resources>
    <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=WindowBrush}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
</Border>

UPDATE
Without static resources:
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <SolidColorBrush Opacity="0.5" Color="White"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>


No, It adds the opacity to the whole element (all elements inside the Border element). I need opacity in the background color.

@AlexWright Added alternative approach
